# Why is WeakReference.Target not null when the target does not show up in memory profilers (dotMemory, ANTS Memory profiler)? [C#]

Tags: c#, wpf, weak-references, memory-profiling

I've recently ran into an issue when having a ViewModel in WPF that subscribes to an event using a weak event pattern. Internally the class that handles the events removes the subscribers whose WeakReference.Target is null (also tried the .IsAlive with same results).

My issue is that the Target is never null. I've used both dotMemory and ANTS Memory profiler and the property that the "Target" points to does not exist in either memory profiler. However, the method callback is still called.

Is there something I'm not understanding about WeakReferences here?

Comment: I'm probably completely wrong, but that sounds like the pointer doesn't exist, not that the pointer exists and what it points to isn't defined (null)